# same model served via TF and TF-serving produce different predictions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

SETUP: a TF model that uses Keras as backend and being saved as 2 files: model.h5 and architechture.json.

GOAL: predict using TF-serving

PROBLEM: prediction values vary in direct call and call to TF-serving (we assume the TF prediction is correct, TF-serving is incorrect)

CURRENT TRIAL:

1. In order to use the model on TF-serving I save the model into Saved_Model format:

```
model = model_from_json(json_string)
model.load_weights(model_path)
export_path = './gModel_Volume/3'
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, export_path)
```

there are several approaches to save it that we tried, all produce same saved_models

2. Load the data from image is same for both setups:

```
X = []
X.append(preprocess_input(img_to_array(load_img(img_url_str, target_size=(260,260)))))
X = np.asarray(X)
```

3a. for plain TF to predict we use:

```
#load:
json_string =  open(architecture_path).read()
gModel = model_from_json(json_string)
gModel.load_weights(model_path)
#predict:
predicted = gModel.predict_on_batch(X)

# predicted = 0.2...
```

3b. for TF-servin via REST-API to predict we use:

```
dataToSend = X.tolist()
predicted = requests.post('http://tf-serving:8501/v1/models/gModel_Volume:predict', json = {"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": dataToSend})

# predicted = -1.17...
```

3c. for TF-servin via gRPC to predict we use:

```
GRPC_MAX_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 4096 * 4096 * 3
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('tf-serving:8500', options=[('grpc.max_receive_message_length', GRPC_MAX_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_LENGTH)])
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
grpc_request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
grpc_request.model_spec.name = 'gModel_Volume'
grpc_request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'
grpc_request.inputs['input_1'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(X))
result = stub.Predict(grpc_request,10)
predicted = result.outputs['dense_1'].float_val[0]

# predicted = -1.17...
```

As one can see the results (0.2 and -1.17) are completely different. Same saved_model was used in all cases.

Note: TF-serving is run under docker-compose and the service "tf-serving" is using the official tensorflow/serving image

I would appreciate any hits and testing suggestions.

If there are better solutions to run multiple TF models in production than TF-serving (except Cloud-based solutions like SageMaker) please share some knowledge with me.

**UPDATE 1:**

- Batching is disabled by default settings, but I disabled it manually too
- There are 4 different models that produce different type of output (single value, set of values, bitmap data). ALL 4 have different result while being served by TFServing and plain TF. Dimensions of the output tensors are fine, values they have are "wrong".

Comment: Can you let us know which version of TF Serving are you using?

Also can you check if the same exists even with batching disabled? You can refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/476#issuecomment-307876090) to understand about why batching affects.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport thank you for your swift reply.

inside docker-compose i use the following code. Does the version 2.6.2 refer to TF-serving version?
`inno-tf-serving:
    image: tensorflow/serving:2.6.2-gpu
    command: --model_config_file=/models/models.config
    volumes:
      - ./models:/models
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
`
also I tried as you proposed to run without batching, updating the usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh content to have **--enable_batching=false**

Comment: Yes 2.6.2 refers to the `TF serving` version and mostly it corresponds to the same version in `TF` as well. Thanks!